# Beautifulsoup: Retrieve specific value in table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to retrieve the value next to 'Annual Report Expense Ratio (net):' on this webpage:

http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=NCHAX+Profile

I am using the libaries beautifulSoup and requests.  My code so far is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
expenseRatioURL = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=NCHAX+Profile'
rawHTML = requests.get(expenseRatioURL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(rawHTML.content)
g_data = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "yfnc_datamodoutline1"})
```

**g_data** is a single element array containing all four tables.

```
type(g_data)
```

returns:

```
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
```

How can I retrieve the percentage next to 'Annual Report Expense Ratio (net):'?

Comment: You have 4 tables in there, at least I have using the LXML parser backend.

Comment: So what is your goal here, to extract the whole *Fees & Expenses* table or just that row?

Comment: Just that specific value beside 'Annual Report Expense Ratio (net):'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p = soup.find(text="Annual Report Expense Ratio (net):").parent.next_sibling.string
```

Comment: Did you peek into my Python buffer? :-) I was still trying to get confirmation that the OP wanted *just* that single value.

Comment: Actually, I have `list(soup.find(text='Annual Report Expense Ratio (net):').parent.next_siblings)` here, so you are off the hook there.